# Points where f(x) = x and g(x) = (lg(x))^3 meet

Tags: functions, logarithms, graphing-functions

I'm trying to find where these two functions meet (lg meaning log base 2), and by continuously fiddling with the calculator i found that when x = 981,970001342... they are equal, but is this the only one? And where does it come from properly, not by guesses.

I tried doing (lg(x))^3 = x (g(x) = f(x)), but i have not been able to find a solution, probably due to my not so good mathematical background.

Comment: Did you try graphing the two functions? What do they look like?

Comment: Using your calculator, by inspection $f(2)=-1$ and $f(3)\approx +1$ shows the smallest root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't solve this analytically without the Lambert W function.  There are many algorithms to find the roots of a function, but they all come down to choosing $x$ values (guided by what you know about the function, including the previous results) and seeing if the function value is small.  There is [another root](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(log(2,x))%5E3%3Dx) at about $2.59092475852820$.  A plot of $\lg^3 x -x$ from $2$ to $1000$ is below.  You can see there are two roots.  You can prove there are no more by showing the derivative does not change sign beyond what you can see.

[image]

Comment: I see. This Lambert W function works for functions different from x*(e^x)?